# VueJS: why can't i call <app-name>.<variable> from anywhere?

Tags: vuejs2, scope, this

okay.  complete retool since people kept getting bogged down in things not related to the question.  so i've boiled it down the the smallest essence:

```html
<script src='_js/vue.2.6.11.js'></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ email }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ email[reportID] }}</h1>
  <hr>
  <button @click='makeItGo'>CLICK</button>
</div>

<script>

var vm = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    email: [],
    reportID: 40,
    info: 'this is info',
  },

  methods: {
    makeItGo() {
      vm.email.push(vm.reportID);
      vm.email[reportID] = info;    <-- this doesn't work.  WHY?
      vm.email[reportID].push(info);   <-- this doesn't work either.  WHY?
    }
  },
});

</script>
```

this will generate the following errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: reportID is not defined"

(found in <Root>)

ReferenceError: "reportID is not defined"
    makeItGo http://localhost/project/test.php line 669 > scriptElement:27
    invokeWithErrorHandling http://localhost/project/_js/vue.2.6.11.js line 669 > scriptElement:1863
    invoker http://localhost/project/_js/vue.2.6.11.js line 669 > scriptElement:2188
    _wrapper http://localhost/project/_js/vue.2.6.11.js line 669 > scriptElement:7547
```

here's the frustration:  WHY does it state that 'reportID' is undefined when it so obviously is.  and WHY does calling it directly (vm.email vs email) not bypass any scoping issues as i would expect it (which is what appears to be the problem)?  in PHP, this just doesn't happen so i'm confused.

all i'm trying to do is dynamically build a nested array.  from there, a short hop to making it associative... i hope.

```
email
  └ 40
    └ 'this is info'
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific on which ones do and do not work? _"Higher level"_ / "_lower level"_ doesn't really mean much

Comment: Also, you have several syntax errors... `params: {app.table, 'SELECT * FROM sweetStuff'}` is all kinds of wrong and you're missing a couple of `)`

Comment: @Phil: one missing bracket.  `params...` works just fine, actually, but i did forget to properly enter the code as used.  fixed now.

Comment: your code block has many problem. Please correct it first and then post your issue

Comment: `params` most certainly does not _"work fine"_. It produces _"SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'"_. You're also still missing a `)` before `.then` so please fix up your code

Comment: yup.  you're correct.  forgot another parenthese.  thank you.  was *very* tired when i wrote the original post.  i've rewritten it for simplicity and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Hoist `this` at the top of your method

`let that = this;`

and then use `that` throughout your method instead of `this`. That way your preserve the scope in each method.

Comment: fair enough, but it doesn't answer the question of why i can't just call it directly with app.<variable>.